# Getting 6 possible URL parameters

Tags: php, regex, url

I am in the midst of writing a simple job board and I have the URL's filtering and working how I want, everything works - I just want to know if I can improve it, if there are any security concerns, and if it is horribly inefficient.

Take the following URL section - foo.com/**in/london/at/google/do/design**

I assign each section a variable and work out the location, company, and category.

Other use cases that work:

- Switching the order - foo.com/**at/google/in/london/do/design**
- Having less parameters - foo.com/**in/london/at/google**

My code to figure out all these variables is:

```
$regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9,-]";
$a = isset($_GET["a"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["a"]) : "";
$aa = isset($_GET["aa"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["aa"]) : "";
$b = isset($_GET["b"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["b"]) : "";
$bb = isset($_GET["bb"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["bb"]) : "";
$c = isset($_GET["c"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["c"]) : "";
$cc = isset($_GET["cc"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["cc"]) : "";

if ($a == "in" && $aa != null) { $searchLocation = $aa; }
if ($b == "in" && $bb != null) { $searchLocation = $bb; }
if ($c == "in" && $cc != null) { $searchLocation = $cc; }

if ($a == "at" && $aa != null) { $searchCompany = $aa; }
if ($b == "at" && $bb != null) { $searchCompany = $bb; }
if ($c == "at" && $cc != null) { $searchCompany = $cc; }

if ($a == "do" && $aa != null) { $searchCategory = $aa; }
if ($b == "do" && $bb != null) { $searchCategory = $bb; }
if ($c == "do" && $cc != null) { $searchCategory = $cc; }

if ($a == "missinghtml") { $errorUrl = true; }
```

I'm looking at this thinking there must be a better to do this. Is this section secure? Any thoughts on this are much appreciated. Like I say it works, but can it be better?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex could be improved:

> ```
> $regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9,-]";
> $a = isset($_GET["a"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["a"]) : "";
> ```

The character `,` shouldn't be in a URL, but `_` can be.
You don't really need to add `/` to the beginning and end of your regex every time.
I see a lot of people do `a-zA-Z` when they could really just do `a-z` with a case `i`nsensitive search.

Becomes:

```
$regex = "/[^a-z0-9-_]/i"
          ^           ^^
$a = isset($_GET["a"]) ? preg_replace($regex, "", $_GET["a"]) : "";
```

---

Using `if ($a == "in" && $aa != null)` could probably be improved also as if `$aa` is not null, then it evaluates to true anyway:

```
if ($a == "in" && $aa)
```

---

With `if ($a == "missinghtml") { $errorUrl = true; }`, you should make it into an else if loop

like:

```
if ($a == "in" && $aa) { $searchLocation = $aa; }
else if ($a == "missinghtml") { $errorUrl = true; }
```

Comment: That's much appreciated, thanks! I will be using commas in the URL, the use case being to search in multiple locations:

 - foo.com/do/design/in/london,liverpool/

Everything else I've updated and it's still working the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the changes already proposed by Quill I strongly hope you reconsider the approach you're taking here.

> I assign each section a variable ...

You can strongly simplify your code by just extracting a group match out of the URL:

```
$regex = '$/(in|at|do)/([^/]+)/$i';
```

Matching this regex will get you your `$search...` as the second group to extract.

under the assertion that a search-identifier will always be followed by it's value and not another identifier you can thus extract your values from the URL as follows:

```
$URL // here's your URL
$locationRegex = '$/in/([^/]+)/$i';
$resultcontainer;
if(preg_match($locationRegex, $URL, $resultcontainer)) {
     $searchLocation = $resultcontainer[1];
}
// and similarly for the other variables
```

now we should put these two approaches together...

```
$url // here's your URL
$pattern = '$/(in|at|do)/([^/]+)/$gi';
$resultContainer;
if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $resultContainer)) {
    // at this point your result container contains up to 6 elements:
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($resulContainer) - 1; $i = $i + 2) {
       switch ($resultContainer[$i]) {
            case "in":
               $searchLocation = $resultContainer[$i + 1];
               break;
            case "at":
               $searchCompany = $resultContainer[$i + 1];
               break;
            case "do":
               $searchCategory = $resultContainer[$i + 1];
               break;
        }
```

This approach basically parses the URL tokens into "key-value-pairs" which might be better stored into a different array structure, but that depends on what you need to do with this later on ;)

Comment: Shouldn't the regex be `(in|at|do)/([^/]+)`?

Comment: @prakharsingh95 my PHP is not the best.. isn't `$` a valid regex delimiter?

Comment: I meant the added `+`. Otherwise the second capture group would be **l** only for **foo/in/london**

Comment: ohhh crap, yes you're completely right

Comment: Thanks guys, I've edited my original question with the updated code I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your combined suggestions, my code looks like this:

```
$regex = "/[^a-z0-9,-\/]/i";
$queryURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."/";
$cleanQueryURL = preg_replace("".$regex."", "", $queryURL);
if(preg_match('/in\/(.+?)\//i', $cleanQueryURL, $resultcontainer)) {
    $searchLocation = $resultcontainer[1];
} else { $searchLocation = "all"; }
if(preg_match('/at\/(.+?)\//i', $cleanQueryURL, $resultcontainer)) {
    $searchCompany = $resultcontainer[1];
} else { $searchCompany = "all"; }
if(preg_match('/do\/(.+?)\//i', $cleanQueryURL, $resultcontainer)) {
    $searchCategory = $resultcontainer[1];
} else { $searchCategory = "all"; }
```

I had to modify the regex slightly, but I used this - https://regex101.com/r/iZ8pV4/1 - and got there in the end!

You guys rock :)